# Show result unwanted row using MySQL select query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select row where status= Y, but MySQL showing also all data where status= N and Y. I want show only data where status= Y.

Here is my following MySQL query:

```
select * from table where status='Y' and keywords like '%cook%' OR category like '%cook%' OR product_name like '%cook%'
```

What can do for showing data where status= Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group your `or` criteria using `(...)`

```
select * from table 
where status='Y' 
and (keywords like '%cook%' 
or category like '%cook%' 
or product_name like '%cook%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below

```
select * from table where status='Y' and (keywords like '%cook%' OR category like '%cook%' OR product_name like '%cook%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 
`status`='Y' AND 
(keywords LIKE '%cook%' OR category LIKE '%cook%' OR product_name LIKE '%cook%')
```